# SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler : Too many email invocations : 11

Tags: apex, batch

I am working on sending mails to 50 clients at one go( basically at lead genration). I was able to send 11 mails until  I used static body through SetHtmlBody() of my Batch class having Database methods. But the problem arises when I have to choose the template dynamically as we have a form having radio buttons. 
Now the same error is coming:  Too many email invocations : 11.

Please help me to sort this error.

Comment: Can you show the source code with your invocation? `Messaging.sendEmailMessage` takes a list. It's usually possible to assemble multiple emails, but send them all in one invocation.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation re governor limits, you can only actually call the `sendEmail` method of the `Messaging` class 10 times.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

You are receiving this message because you will have called it 11 times in the same context.  Depending on your use case, there are a couple of ways to circumnavigate this. If you really do need to call the `sendEmail` method more than 10 times, you could use a Batch Apex class and set your batch size to 1 (to 10 depending how you implement it).  This would allow you to call the method 10 times per execute iteration. See this blog entry for details:

http://forceguru.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-send-more-than-10-e-mails.html

Its not clear from your post whether that is what you want to do, but you can also send the same email to multiple addresses using the following format:

```
setToAddresses( new String[] {address1, address2, address3} )
```

Or, different emails to different addresses using something like:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
// add mails to list here
Messaging.sendEmail( mails );
```

See the documentation here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer on how to do this already on a similar question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3999/60

In summary, Messaging.sendEmail accepts a List, which means each call to it can include a large number of emails to send - you need to bulkify your send email calls just like you would in an apex trigger.

Comment: lol, I was on holiday when you did that one, that's my excuse and i'm sticking to it ;)